Avoid setting GitHub Action variables in case the passed input is empty
I am creating a CI/CD that makes extensive use for re-usable workflows and inputs. The script in question is used to run a Terraform pipeline that creates a set of resources on Azure. For those resources, Terraform contains default values for most of the expected inputs meaning that the CI script needs not to set any kind of variables.
That being said, I have a need to spin up an new environment with different configuration. To do so I have enhanced the base workflow script to accept some configuration parameters as inputs in the following manner:
      # AKS specific variables
      aks-enable-autoscale:
        type: boolean
        description: Whether to enable AKS autoscale or not
        required: false
      aks-vm-size:
        type: string
        description: The VM size use for the AKS node-pool
        required: false
      aks-sku-tier:
        type: string
        description: The SKU tier for the AKS cluster
        required: false

and I am setting them as part of the environment like so:
  # AKS specific variables
  TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_auto_scaling_enabled : ${{ inputs.aks-enable-autoscale }}
  TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_vm_size              : ${{ inputs.aks-vm-size }}
  TF_VAR_aks_sku_tier                               : ${{ inputs.aks-sku-tier }}

Since those inputs are not required, I am calling the workflow sometimes providing and other not. In the latter case the value of the TF_VAR_* variables is empty. I was under the impression that setting those to a null or empty value would automatically omit them from being set in the environment.
I am a bit confused on how to handle this. I can mitigate the problem for now, simply by providing the default values found in Terraform as inputs but ideally I would like to keep my CI scripts and pass in only the values I need to.
How can I achieve this?

IIUC, when certain inputs are empty, you want the respective TF_VAR_* variables not to be visible at all for consumption by next steps, right? If yes, when empty (null), those variables are omitted by the subsequent steps?

Something like this might work:
name: env-dynamic

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      # AKS specific variables
      aks-enable-autoscale:
        type: boolean
        description: Whether to enable AKS autoscale or not
        required: false
      aks-vm-size:
        type: string
        description: The VM size use for the AKS node-pool
        required: false
      aks-sku-tier:
        type: string
        description: The SKU tier for the AKS cluster
        required: false

jobs:
  create-env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create dynamic environment
        id: create
        run: |
          json="{}"

          # Read name-value pairs
          while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
            if [ -n "$value" ] && [ $value != null ]; then
              if [ $value = true ] || [ $value = false ] || [[ $value =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                json=$(echo "$json" | jq -c --arg key "$key" --argjson value "$value" '. + {($key): $value}')
              else
                json=$(echo "$json" | jq -c --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '. + {($key): $value}')
              fi
            fi
          done <<EOF
          TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_auto_scaling_enabled=${{ input.aks-enable-autoscale }}
          TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_vm_size=${{ input.aks-vm-size }}
          TF_VAR_aks_sku_tier=${{ input.aks-sku-tier }}
          EOF

          echo env=$json >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Apply dynamic environment
        run: |
          echo $TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_auto_scaling_enabled
          echo $TF_VAR_aks_default_node_pool_vm_size
          echo $TF_VAR_aks_sku_tier
        env: ${{ fromJson( steps.create.outputs.env ) }}

